# BitBucket - "You are not an admin of any teams" | how to create a project?

Tags: bitbucket

I just created a brand new account on BitBucket and made my initial commit. I want to create a new project for each new magento module, so that I can clone them separately and work on them parallel to the main repository.

But if I try to create the project then I get "You are not an admin of any teams. Only team admins have the ability to create projects."

How can I get admin?

Comment: Is it Cloud or Self-Hosted?

Comment: It is Cloud hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to create a new team first or join one, then you can create a new project

Comment: Yes, you need a "Team" -> https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-t-create-project-without-a-team/qaq-p/758498